# Difference in Chain Types

Tags: maintenance, chain, drivetrain

What is the difference in chain types, some say 11 speed, some say 9.

Is the only difference length, what would happen if i put an 11 speed chain on my 9 speed cassette ?

thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The amount of room on the rear wheel hub for the sprocket cassette is limited. In order to get more sprockets into the cassette, they have to be closer together. To 
accommodate this chains have to be made narrower.

The *internal* width (the width of the rollers between the inner plates) is the same for different speed chains - 3⁄32" (2.4 mm). The *external* width is less for higher speed chains.

It's my understanding that using a 1-speed higher chain is generally workable, but 2-speeds higher will definitely cause shifting problems.

The spacing of chainrings on the cranks also has to be narrower for higher speed chains.  I believe there is the possibility for a too-narrow chain to drop in between the chainrings if used with lower speed cranksets.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in width, not length.
I guess you will be ok with that chain (but not the other way: 9 speed chain won't fit with even 10 speed sprocket), but 9 speed chain can be much cheaper.

More info here: https://sheldonbrown.com/speeds.html

Comment: Shifting performance can be decreased using the wrong width of chain - it changes slower because it takes longer to move and settle to the new cog.

Comment: Is there much noticeable difference between a cheep and high cost chain?

Comment: @garyconstable - that;s just my experience, but cheaper ones (like kmc) last much less than more expensive (like shimano)